# String splitting problems in Erlang

Tags: erlang

I've been playing around with the splitting of atoms and have a problem with strings. The input data will always be an atom that consists of some letters and then some numbers, for instance `ms444`, `r64` or `min1`. Since the function `lists:splitwith/2` takes a list the atom is first converted into a list:

```
24> lists:splitwith(fun (C) -> is_atom(C) end, [m,s,4,4,4]).
{[m,s],[4,4,4]}
25> lists:splitwith(fun (C) -> is_atom(C) end, atom_to_list(ms444)).
{[],"ms444"}
26> atom_to_list(ms444).
"ms444"
```

I want to separate the letters from the numbers and I've succeeded in doing that when using a list, but since I start out with an atom I get a "string" as result to put into my `splitwith` function...

Is it interpreting each item in the list as a string or what is going on?

Comment: Can you clarify the structure of your original strings? Fixed-width, always one continuous set of digits, etc..

Comment: This is a poor use case for atoms. Unless you find yourself in a situation where you can't control the contents of the input at all, needing to "split atoms" is an indication of structural issues in the rest of the code. This is why they are called "atoms" to begin with. At the *very* least these should be tuples: `'ms444'` should have been `{ms, 444}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since strings in Erlang are just a `list()` of `integer()` the test in the fun will be made if the item is an `atom()` when it is in fact an `integer()`. If the test is changed to look for letters it works:

```
29> lists:splitwith(fun (C) -> (C >= $a) and (C =< $Z)  end, atom_to_list(ms444)).
{"ms","444"}
```

Comment: There is no need to use atom_to_list/1 here. Just write "ms444" (with quotes) and you will get a string (list of integers).

Comment: Well agreed, but it looks wonky if the atom in question is a variable as it would be in a real program. Would it even work then?

Comment: Yes there is, ms444 is an atom.

Answer (score 9):

You might want to have a look at the string module documentation:

http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/string.html

The following function might interest you:

```
tokens(String, SeparatorList) -> Tokens
```

Comment: No, wouldn't work, I need all characters intact. There are no "throwaway" characters in there.

Answer (score 1):

An atom in erlang is a named constant and not a variable (or not like a variable is in an imperative language).
You should really not create atoms in dynamic fashion (that is, don't convert things to atoms at runtime)

They are used more in pattern matching and send recive code.

```
Pid ! {matchthis, X}


recive
{foobar,Y} -> doY(Y);
{matchthis,X} -> doX(X);
Other -> doother(Other)
end
```

A variable, like X  could be set to an atom. For example   X=if 1==1 -> ok; true -> fail end. I could suffer from poor imagination but I can't think of a way why you would like to parse atom. You should be in charge of what atoms you write and not use `list_to_atom`(CharIntegerList).

Can you perhaps give a more overview of what you like to accomplish?

Comment: What I'm doing is parsing an ASN1 spec that has been compiled into erlang and where certain enums have been translated into atoms, ms480 for instance, means that there should be a 480 ms delay between sendings of a certain signal.

Comment: ah.
I suppose its impossible to make that "any other way". (To mee it seems a bit odd to have the specs as atoms that way ms480 instead of {ms,480}but we are all slaves to the masters.) So what happens is that someone parses text into atoms, you take the atoms and convert them to strings,s split them  and I suppose that you after that convert "480" into a number.

Answer (score 0):

A "string" in Erlang is not a primitive type: it is just a list() of integers(). So if you want to "separate" the letters from the digits, you'll have to do comparison with the integer representation of the characters.